# How To Validation This Class?(WPF)

Tags: wpf, validation, properties

How To Validation This Class?(WPF)

I can not understand is the Property **Value** for each.

For this method : public override ValidationResult Validate(object **value**.

name maximum char must be 10;
age maximum value must be 150;

```
public class Person : ValidationRule
    {
        string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

        int _age = 20;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

        string _Phone = "000-0000";

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return _Phone; }
            set { _Phone = value; }
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            **//is value Which Property?**
              //I can not understand is the Property Value for each
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make your class derive from `ValidationRule`:  it's a person, not a rule.

First, I don't recommend that WPF developers use validation rules at all.  Use MVVM, and have your view model implement `IDataErrorInfo` as described (for instance) [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/).

If you want to create a single `ValidationRule` class to validate your `Person` class, you can, but you'll need to create a `PropertyName` property on the class and set it in your XAML, e.g.:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age"
             Mode="TwoWay">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:PersonValidationRule PropertyName="Age"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Then the `Validate` method in this class can look at the `PropertyName` and branch accordingly.  Of course, now you've implemented a new point of failure - what happens if you put down the wrong property name in your XAML?  If you use data-error validation, that can't happen.